# Meaning of $\partial f /\partial x$

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, partial-derivative

I have an exercise in complex analysis that begins,

> If $U\subset \mathbb C$ is an open set and $f:U\to \mathbb C$ is real differentiable....

Later on, it allows me to assume $f$ is holomorphic.
It also mentions $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$$
I am unsure of what this is.

Is this
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\tag 1$$
or is it 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\tag 2$$ 
or something else?

I believe it is $(1)$ using a tree diagram, but it has been a while. I am unsure.

Comment: try with $f(z) = C z^k$ you'll see what it means

Comment: @user1952009 Great suggestion. Thanks

Comment: and after that with $f(z) = C |z|^2$  (which is real differentiable but not complex differentiable (holomorphic))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $$f(x + yi) = f(x,y) = u(x,y) + v(x,y)i$$
then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} i $$

Comment: Of course since taking partial derivatives is linear (I think) then you can just take the partial derivative on both sides. I presume this means that $\partial f/\partial y = \partial u/\partial y+i\partial v/\partial y $. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right......

Comment: I understand. Thanks!